# Unable to select value in action intermediate page

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-forms, django-admin

I have two models `User` and `Group`.
I'm implementing an action "Change Groups" in `UsersAdmin` that redirects to an intermediate page with 2 MultipleChoiceFields for Groups, that I want to be used to either remove users from certain groups, add users to other groups, or do both in one go (i.e. move them).
[The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages) are very short about this subject, so in order to do this, I'm following [this article](https://okhlopkov.medium.com/how-to-create-django-admin-actions-with-and-without-intermediate-page-b48ff977b029).

Here's my form:

```py
class ChangeUsersGroupsForm(forms.Form):
    _selected_action = forms.CharField(widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput)
    from_groups = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Group.objects, required=False)
    to_groups = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Group.objects, required=False)
```

My admin action:

```py
def change_groups_action(self, request, queryset):
    if 'apply' in request.POST:
        from_groups = request.POST["from_groups"]
        to_groups = request.POST["to_groups"]

        from_groups_qs = Group.objects.filter(pk__in=from_groups).all()
        to_groups_qs = Group.objects.filter(pk__in=to_groups).all()
        user_ids = [u.user_id for u in queryset]

        # task that will do the job of actually moving the users
        change_users_groups.delay(from_groups_qs, to_groups_qs)

        self.message_user(request, "Changed groups of %s users" % len(user_ids))

        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())

    form = ChangeUsersGroupsForm(initial={'_selected_action': queryset.values_list('id', flat=True)})

    return render(request, "admin/change_users_groups.html", {'queryset': queryset, 'form': form})
change_groups_action.short_description = "Change Groups"
```

Here's my template:

```html
<!-- users/templates/admin/change_users_groups.html -->

{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %} {% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  <br />
  <br />
  <p>The Group changes will be applied to the following users:</p>
  <ul>
    {{ queryset|unordered_list }}
  </ul>
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="change_groups_action" />
  <input type="submit" name="apply" value="Confirm" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is how the intermediate page renders:
[image: intermediate page form]

First (but minor) issue is that the form fields are displayed in a row, instead of each in one row. But let's skip that for now.

The big issue is that when I select a Group, nothing happens, the Group doesn't seem to be selected.
Instead I see the following error on the browser Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: django.jQuery is not a function
```

This error is printed every time I click on an option.

Anyone knows what's going on?

---

Django 2.2
Python 3.8.10

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before, but in different situation (unrelated to Django admin). I almost always turned out to be because JQuery was not loaded or it was loaded too late in the template.

According to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#jquery):

> If you want to use jQuery in your own admin JavaScript without
> including a second copy, you can use the django.jQuery object on
> changelist and add/edit views. Also, your own admin forms or widgets
> depending on django.jQuery must specify js=['admin/js/jquery.init.js',
> …] when declaring form media assets.

So that would make your form class look like:

```py
class ChangeUsersGroupsForm(forms.Form):
    _selected_action = forms.CharField(widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput)
    from_groups = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Group.objects, required=False)
    to_groups = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Group.objects, required=False)

    class Media:
        js = ['admin/js/jquery.init.js']
```

Regarding your form field form. I suggest rendering each field separately like so:

```html
{{ form.from_groups }}
<br/>
{{ form.to_groups }}
```

This seems like the simplest solution

Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not doing it. (sorry I took a while to answer, I moved on to other stuff and just got back to this)